# Spawn time and speed move in Unity game (similar to the Piano Tiles)

Tags: unity-game-engine, time, velocity, tiles, spawn

I do not know how to ride spawnTime and speedMove that when i increase speedMove does not distinguish between the tiles:
[The increased difference between the tiles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQFfV.png)

speedMove in code:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y * speedMove * Time.deltaTime);
```

spawnTime in code:

```
InvokeRepeating("Spawn", spawnDelay, spawnTime);
```

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
Spawner.spawnTime = (Enemy.height / Enemy.speedMove);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using Time.fixedDeltaTime instead of Time.deltaTime.

Time.deltaTime vary according to FPS whereas Time.fixedDeltaTime doesn't.
So with Time.deltaTime you create linear velocity that depends on FPS.